# How to make Atom see correct Python version of the virtual environment?

Tags: python, atom-editor

Installed Anaconda and created virtual Env. for python 3.8.2.
When I check python version though Atom I see following:

[image]

If I want to have a look at the python version through terminal I see another version:

[image]

As you can see ***py38*** environment is activated Atom says that I have Python 2.7.16 but the Terminal says that I have 3.8.2. I installed 3.8.2 but Atom doesn't take it into account.

How can I change python version in Atom to installed one?

Answer (score 0):

So as usual answer is very simple. I see different python versions because every app uses it's own path for python. So Anaconda uses path that leads to python 2.7, as Terminal uses path that leads to python 3.8.

The only thing left to do is find how to change path for the Atom to have correct version of the python.